# Mensagem indevida no rodapé do site ("TODO: Remove after April Fools 2023 is done")

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

No rodapé do site aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
// TODO: Remove after April Fools 2023 is done
```

Segue imagem:

[image: Mensagem indevida de primeiro de abril]

Como ainda faltam quase 3 semanas para 1 de abril, e não me parece que isso será parte das [tradicionais brincadeiras](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/april-fools/), acho que é um bug mesmo, certo?

---

Obs: o mesmo problema também foi reportado no [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387507/401803), mas pelo jeito [já foi corrigido](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387509/401803).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema também foi [reportado no MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387507/208518), e entretanto corrigido — conforme mencionado na própria pergunta.